# HTML/CSS tables don't allign, text in tables still pad

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a problem where everything is just messed up. I've tried a couple of solutions, but my Profile Page won't align as it should. I Want everything to be in the center and be clean. Here's an example of what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sWfr.jpg Also, how do I add a right border AKA add a border between **Username:** and **Edmin**.

```
<main>
<div class="container body-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main" class="col-md-9">
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <style>
                    table {
                        border-spacing: 0;
                        margin:0;
                        padding: 0;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 50%;
                    }
                    table, th, td {
                        margin:0;
                        padding: 0;
                        border: 3px solid black;
                    }
                    th {
                        margin:0;
                        padding: 0;
                        background-color: #2c3e50;
                        color: white;
                        text-align: center;
                        height: 50px;
                    }
                </style>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <img style="height: 250px; width: 250px; border:8px dashed #2c3e50" hspace="100" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + ${image}}"  /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="image">Change profile picture</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" placeholder="Image" name="multipartFile" required="required"/>
                        <span class="help-block">Profile picture can be up to 32 MBs</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>E-mail:</th>
                        <th><span th:text="${user.email}"><br/></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <th> <span th:text="${user.fullName}"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username:</th>
                        <th> <span th:text="${user.username}"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Age:</th>
                        <th><span th:text="${user.age}"><br/></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table, th, td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, that fixed the text layout INSIDE the table(All of the items in the table are now aligned properly), but the whole table is still on the left and not the center like the image.

Comment: I've edited the code. I removed margin: 0 from table, th, td and added margin: 0 auto to table.

https://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/vWjVRg

Comment: Should be working, will test it after 4 hours as I messed up something in the backend so back to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use one table containing multiple rows.

Don't put every row in a table of its own.

(And don't use `th` elements for data cells, use `td` for that. Use `th` only for heading cells).